# ContourPlot3D gives confusing plot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced after 9.0, persisting through 13.2.**

---

```
ContourPlot3D [z == Sqrt@(x + y), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, - 5, 5},
AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},AxesLabel->{x,y,z}]
```

[image]

z < 0, there is also some graph?

ContourPlot gives a true plot.

```
ContourPlot[y==Sqrt[x],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]
```

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, add `RegionFunction -> (#3 >= 0 &),
RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`

Comment: That Sqrt gives negative values for  arguments near zero in the 3D plot  looks like a bug to me. Please report it to support@wofram.com.

Comment: Version 9.0.1 is not influenced.