# Quality options in DiscretizeRegion do not work (Plot 3D ParametricRegion with smooth surfaces)

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

**WRI confirmed the bugs in the quality options in `DiscretizeRegion` on 14/Nov/2022**

---

I'm trying to plot the region defined by the following inequalities in 3D:

```
Sqrt[x^2+y^2-z^2]+Sqrt[-x^2+y^2+z^2]+Sqrt[x^2-y^2+z^2]<=Sqrt[2]&&0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&0<=z<=1
```

Adopting the parameterization in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275933/63563), I used the following code

```
Clear[sol, expr, reg, meshreg];
sol = SolveValues[{u^2 == x^2 + y^2 - z^2, v^2 == -x^2 + y^2 + z^2, 
    w^2 == x^2 - y^2 + z^2}, {x, y, z}];
expr = sol // Last;
reg = ParametricRegion[{expr, 
    u + v + w <= Sqrt[2]}, {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}, {w, 0, 2}}];
Region[reg]
```

The output figure does not have smooth surfaces:

[image: plot with the surfaces being not smooth]

I tried to use `DiscretizeRegion` to get a smoother surface by specifying `MaxCellMeasure`, `MeshQualityGoal`, and `AccuracyGoal`. But none of them changed the smoothness of the surface. For example:

```
meshreg = 
  DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[{Red, Opacity[.5]}], meshreg}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

produces:

[image]

with an error message:

> DiscretizeRegion::drtol: Tolerance requested by the AccuracyGoal and
> PrecisionGoal options is too small to be achieved. Increasing to
> absolute tolerance 2.5809568279517847`*^-8

Ideally, I would like to have perfectly smooth surfaces (up to human eye precision..)

How to obtain it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

- I also don't know why `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"` make no smooth effect.
- Here we use the same methods in my previous answer,that is, at first deform the plot of `RegionPlot3D` and then using `DiscretizeGraphics`.
- It seems that `RegionPlot3D` can not directly handle the complex variable function `Sqrt`. We can test this by `RegionPlot3D[ And @@ {0 <=  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - z^2] + Sqrt[-x^2 + y^2 + z^2] +  Sqrt[x^2 - y^2 + z^2] <= Sqrt[2],  x^2 + y^2 - z^2 >= 0, -x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 0,  x^2 - y^2 + z^2 >= 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},  PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4]`

```
Clear[sol, expr, plot,newplot, reg];
sol = SolveValues[{u^2 == x^2 + y^2 - z^2, v^2 == -x^2 + y^2 + z^2, 
    w^2 == x^2 - y^2 + z^2}, {x, y, z}];
expr = sol // Last;
plot = RegionPlot3D[
    u + v + w <= Sqrt[2], {u, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {v, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {w, 0, 
     Sqrt[2]}, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    PlotPoints -> 80]
newplot=plot /. {u_Real, v_Real, w_Real} -> expr;
reg =newplot // DiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

- The case when `-1<=x<=1,-1<=y<=1,-1<=z<=1`.

```
Clear[sol, plot];
sol = SolveValues[{u^2 == x^2 + y^2 - z^2, v^2 == -x^2 + y^2 + z^2, 
    w^2 == x^2 - y^2 + z^2}, {x, y, z}];
plot = RegionPlot3D[
   u + v + w <= Sqrt[2], {u, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {v, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {w, 0, 
    Sqrt[2]}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   PlotRange -> Sqrt[2]];
DiscretizeGraphics /@ (plot /. {u_Real, v_Real, w_Real} -> # & /@ 
    sol) // RegionUnion
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just filed a report regarding the issues with `RegionPlot3D` and the quality options in `DescritizeRegion` to WRI.

Comment: If WRI confirmed this as a bug, please add the CASE number to the question header.