# ContourPlot3D graph issues

Tags: plotting

I am attempting to see the contour plot for the function,
Sqrt[y-x]==z. The graph shows an odd structure that seems to fall where a vertical asymptote would exist.  What can I do to eliminate the odd structure? Here is my code for it:

```
ContourPlot3D[Sqrt[y-x]==z,{x,-6,6},{y,0,6},{z,0,4}]
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[Re[Sqrt[y - x]] == z, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I am fairly new to Mathematica.  I knew there was a real number issue just by what was going on in the graph.  I was unaware that adding the Re would only allow real number output.  This helps tremendously.

Comment: @BobHanlon `ContourPlot3D[Re[Sqrt[y - x]] == z, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]` will get the wrong result.  The result contain a part of `z==0` and `y<=x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug.

- [ContourPlot3D gives confusing plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263997/contourplot3d-gives-confusing-plot)
- [CountourPlot3D wrong plotting result with extra surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275930/countourplot3d-wrong-plotting-result-with-extra-surfaces/275933#275933)

we have to remove `Sqrt` from the original equation.

```
ContourPlot3D[y - x == z^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 4}]
```

Or

```
ContourPlot3D[y - x == z^2, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z >= 0], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Or use `ImplicitRegion`, still avoid `Sqrt`.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{y - x == z^2, 
   z >= 0}, {{x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, -4, 4}}]
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@reg, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Mesh -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: I must have accidently hit a downvote a day or so ago from my iPhone .  I just now corrected it to an upvote.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @JimB Thanks :)